# React Navigation: Why doesn't minified file in `lib` directory update when I change corresponding file in `src`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm using Material Top Tab navigator in my React Native app. Specifically, I use the function `createMaterialTopTabNavigator()` which is found in `react-navigation-tabs`. `react-navigation-tabs` contains the file `lib -> module -> views -> MaterialTopTabBar.js`, which is a minified file corresponding to `src -> views -> MaterialTopTabBar.tsx`. I wanted to change something in `MaterialTopTabBar.tsx` because I might fork the module, but when I edited `MaterialTopTabBar.tsx`, even when I re-ran `react-native run-ios`, `MaterialTopTabBar.js` (in `lib`) didn't get updated. When I edited `MaterialTopTabBar.js` (the minified file) directly, the changes did show.

Does anyone know why `MaterialTopTabBar.js` doesn't get updated when I change `MaterialTopTabBar.tsx` and re-build the project?

**UPDATE:** I think it's that `MaterialTopTabBar.tsx` was transpiled to `MaterialTopTabBar.js` before the module was shipped, rather than when I build the project. One way I was able to solve the problem was to manually convert the Typescript code in `MaterialTopTabBar.tsx` to JS, and paste it into `MaterialTopTabBar.js`.

Answer (score 0):

not lil data. I do not know if the `bundler proccess` is run by webpack or some else. but let's take CRA for example. The `webpack-dev-server`

has the following

```js
// for some reason broken when imported through webpack. If you just want to
// use an image, put it in `src` and `import` it from JavaScript instead.
        contentBase: paths.appPublic,
        contentBasePublicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
        // By default files from `contentBase` will not trigger a page reload.
        watchContentBase: true,
        // Enable hot reloading server. It will provide WDS_SOCKET_PATH endpoint
```

so you need to find the place were contentBase and stuff are declare